# Plagiarizing a published paper in introduction?

Tags: plagiarism

I was reading a math preprint on archives (not yet published), and in the introduction the authors say "Following author X in [ref]..." and go on to set up the problem. When I went to [ref], it turns out the authors of the preprint actually take three paragraphs *word for word* from [ref] and included them in their introduction. It is not something essential, just a few general comments and background stuff; still, they are *entirely* identical.

Is this appropriate? Just saying "Following X...." makes it okay? To me, it still looks like plagiarising X's work.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what kind of background stuff this is? Copying exact statements of definitions and theorems [can be appropriate](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/167906/17254).

Comment: It is more than that. There are a couple of narrative paragraphs on general properties of the mathematical objects in question.  It is nothing novel in there, the information itself is well-know. Still, the wording and notations are exactly as in the published paper.

Comment: It's certainly inappropriate. The copied words should be in quotation marks.

Comment: Is the quoted section in a separate paragraph? Maybe in the original paper layout the fact that the referenced text is a quote is more clear.  "A new paragraph with narrower margins" is an alternative method of quoting attributed text.

Comment: There are several sections which are word for word, about 3/4 of a page. There is no special layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually it sounds more like copyright infringement than plagiarism. That would be true if the word were copied verbatim, but there were few original creative ideas in it. If the writer isn't claiming ideas of others as their own, then it isn't plagiarism.

Note that plagiarism and copyright infringement are nearly orthogonal you can have either, both, or neither, depending on what is written. You can, in particular, plagiarize using none of the words of the original. You can also infringe copyright without plagiarizing if the copied words have no intellectual content or if they are copied but also cited. And the latter is also true if you copy things that are common knowledge.

Likewise the motivations for the two can be quite different (or the same).

This confusion is very common if I can judge by the evidence on this site.

Comment: I refereed a paper that had about 50% of one section copy pasted from a previous paper that was published in a different journal and with a different publisher. I left a note to the editor that I was concerned about copyright infringement. There were many other issues with the paper, but that was a very interesting issue.

Comment: –1. Plagiarism is defined to be taking someone else's ideas *or work* and passing it off as your own. Copying somebody else's words for three paragraphs without making it explicitly clear that it's a direct quote is passing off somebody else's work as one's own.

Answer (score 3):

You have a point there; at the very least what is taken word for word should be in quotes to make clear it is quoted. Technically this is not OK.

On the other hand, *if this is the only problematic bit* I'd say it's a minor issue. How much would've been won had the preprint authors reworded this slightly so nobody couldn't accuse them anymore? Not much I'd say. Ultimately it is the own work of the authors that counts, which isn't affected. Also, the source is acknowledged, if in an arguably insufficient way.

Comment: Could this constitute copyright infringement on the published article?

Comment: @Markus I'm definitely not a lawyer, but within a non-commercial research article, I suspect a sufficiently short recitation of a short part of a longer article in a directly relevant manner could argue a fair use/fair dealing/whatever research defence exists in the relevant jurisdiction. Of course, if those three paragraphs constituted the whole article (or it's major thesis) there might still be a legal problem. Which as Buffy points out in another answer is mostly orthogonal to the question of academic misconduct.

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider this "minor"... while of course there are many worse situations that can happen, still if people became aware of this I think it would hurt the author's credibility, especially if they did this kind of thing regularly. And if a few paragraphs from my article were being copy/pasted, I would point it out to the author and expect them to correct the situation. For context, my field is physics, and I'm assuming this question refers to "general introductory text," not a precise statement of a theorem.

Comment: I guess the author's excuse would be that he started with "Following X in [ref]...". But in my opinion presenting someone else's setup doesn't allow to actually copy verbatim a big part of the introduction. One should do this in their own words, even if the essence of what is translated is almost identical.